# Three.js setPixelRatio crash on IOS browser

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a three.js website. I load a json with ObjectLoader.

All is fine with each platform: win-all browsers-desktop, android phone-all browsers.
Only IOS(Ipad Air) has problems with all browsers(Chrome, Safari, Mercury), almost all the times, the browser crashes.

Logs tell the issue is: Jetsam - low memory.
The problem seems to be the setPixelRatio function, if I comment the line all is fine.
Without the setPixelRatio the 3d solid is a little blurred, less clear and sharp.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
function load3D()
{
    var callbackProgress = function( progress ) {

    };

    var callbackError = function(  ) {
        console.log('error');
    };

    var asseturl='test.json';

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load( asseturl, function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );
        stageResize();

    }, callbackProgress, callbackError);

}

function stageResize()
{
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); //this row gives browser crash
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after struggling for months I found the solution.

If you use setPixelRatio you have set antilias to false on the WebGLRenderer

Found it on that post:
https://rubenborgonjen.com/knowledge_three_js_update.html